# Supertest is throwing expected 200 OK, got 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js, supertest

I am creating and running unit test cases.

This is my code:

```
const app = require('../../index')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const request = supertest(app)

it('Positive flow', (done) => {
        let reqObj = {
            "name": "Qwerty",
            "class": 2
        }

        let resObj = {
            "success": "yes",
            "message": "done"
        }
  
        const response = request.post('/calculation')
            .send(reqObj)
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) return done(err)
                response.expect(200)
                response.expect(expect.objectContaining(resObj))
                return done()
        })
})
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./router')
const PORT = 7000 
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);

module.exports = app;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`PORT:${PORT}`));
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const func = require('./calculation')
router.post('/calculation', func.calc)
module.exports = router
```

calculation

```
const models = require('../models')
const calc = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const calculation = await models.USER_LICENSE.create({
            name: req.name,
            class: req.class,
        });
        return res.status(200).json({"success": "yes", "message":"done"})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({"success": "no", "message":"fail"})
    }
}
```

I am using sequelize to store data into postgresql. I am adding a new record into a database. I want to add a unit test for this code for which I have attached the code.
Everytime I run the test, I am getting the follwing error

```
expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"
```

On postman I am getting correct results.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code under test?

Comment: @LinDu I have added the code. I forgot to comment back.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. It works fine for me.